# Display dates not in ascending for To_Char

Tags: oracle-11g

can i know why and how i can solve the problem whereby if i use To_Char it does not sort the date in ascending. Below is my code

```
    select distinct To_Char (attendance_Date, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
    from DIT_2010MAR_CIT4114A_FYP1_NO
    order by 1 asc
```

result obtained is

```
DATE     
----------
01/05/2016
02/05/2016
03/04/2016
04/04/2016
05/04/2016
06/04/2016
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you sort by dates formatted in DD/MM/YYYY, then the sorting will put all the first of month first (of every month), then the seconds of month, etc.

You can't sort by a column not included in a select distinct, though. To sort by ascending date, group by and use the actual date column instead of the formatted date via to_char:

```
select To_Char (attendance_Date, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
from DIT_2010MAR_CIT4114A_FYP1_NO
group by attendance_Date
order by attendance_Date asc
```

If `attendance_Date` is a timestamp, cast it to date first (everywhere in the query).

Comment: i tried this earlier but i am getting an error message stating not a selected expression

Comment: @Programmer ah, of course, because of the distinct! Try Group By attendance_Date instead (if it is a datetime, cast it to date)

Comment: thx for rectifying the problem.